# Centering a CardView within a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, css

I've been playing around with CardViews inside a RecyclerView, but can't seem to get my cards centered.

My `cardview.xml`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My `activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Image of what my app looks like when I run it:

[image]

Comment: Try to add `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` to your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @michal.z Just tried it now, still the same.

Answer (score 6):

Okok, I have the same question and I think I have "solved" it. It's really just another hack. The android team at Google really should fix this recycler view and add support for swipe to dismiss.

In onCreateView:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemDecoration() {

  @Override
  public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, State state) {
    int totalWidth = parent.getWidth();
    int maxCardWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.card_max_width);
    int sidePadding = (totalWidth - maxCardWidth) / 2;
    sidePadding = Math.max(0, sidePadding);
    outRect.set(sidePadding, 0, sidePadding, padding);
  }
});
```

Comment: To make a view center , it should be  `outRect(0,sidePadding,0,sidePadding)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `LinearLayout`'s `android:layout_width` as `match_parent` in order for `android:gravity="center"` to take effect.

Comment: Tried it, and it's still aligning to the left.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. My RecyclerView is inside a SwipeRefreshLayout, so I found out I could center it with the SwipeRefreshLayout.

```
<style name="swipe_refresh_cards_layout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/swipe_refresh_cards_width</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

I'm using a dimens.xml file for various screen sizes here.

Not the best solution IMO, but it works. I also found it to work (not using the solution above) if I put a LinearLayout as the parent to the SwipeRefreshLayout with

```
<style name="inner_layout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/swipe_refresh_cards_width</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping up your Cardview inside a LinearLayout with width set to match_parent and android:gravity = "center".

Answer (score 0):

Just set your parent's(in your case LinearLayout) width to match_parent.